# Azure Synapse Serverless Command Displays Special Characters Instead of Chinese Characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, azure-synapse-analytics

I am facing an issue while running the 'serverless' command on the terminal in Azure Synapse. The command seems to display special characters (question marks) instead of correctly rendering Chinese characters.

For example, the text "南京1月装卸费" is being changed to "??1????".

I have tried adjusting the collation and encoding settings in my SQL query, using the 'Chinese_PRC_CI_AI' collation, and ensuring that the data is stored in delta/parquet. However, the problem persists.

Here is an excerpt from my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    PurchaseOrderLineDescription,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), PurchaseOrderLineDescription) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AI AS PurchaseOrderLineDescription1
FROM  
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://dbstorageda0s.dfs.core.windows.net/BC2.0-IP/TransformLayer/Facts/Views/CoupaPurchaseOrder/',
        FORMAT = 'DELTA'
    ) AS coupapurchaseorder_ipspend_test 
WHERE 
    PurchaseOrderNumber IN ('4523955603', 'PO15044020', 'PO15164185');
```

Comment: You should use format file where indicate that you have unicode instead of convert to unicode, your characters are lost prior to conversion as read as ascii thats's why you receive "?".For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/format-files-for-importing-or-exporting-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with a UTF-8 encoding issue that's conflicting with the current database's default collation setting. Have you tried to use a staging table (either a user table, #temp table or @table variable) that uses a column definition like `PurchaseOrderLineDescription VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8` into which the `OPENROWSET` data can be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Facing issues with the 'serverless' command in Azure Synapse displaying question marks instead of Chinese characters, adjusting collation at the column level might not be sufficient.

To resolve this, try altering the collation at the database level using the following SQL command:

```
USE Master;
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CS_AS_KS_WS;
```

Replace YourDatabaseName and customize the collation as needed, using AI/AS, KA/KI, and WS/WI based on your data characteristics.

After applying the database-level collation, retry the 'serverless' command. Ensure your data encoding and format (delta/parquet) are also set correctly.

Remember to take backups before making changes. If issues persist, review encoding settings and data formats.